# Can't open R (4.0.3) even though it's installed on Ubuntu (20.04) - Fatal error: unable to open the base package

Tags: r, ubuntu, installation

I used to run R 3.6 but I updated it to 4.0.3 and now I can't even open R. I'm not sure how I managed to break it. I followed the installation instructions on [this](https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/) and [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-18-04/) site.

When I run `R --version` on the command line it looks like R is installed:

```
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10) -- "Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out" Copyright
(C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing Platform:
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
```

But when I try to start R by typing `R` I get an error:

```
Fatal error: unable to open the base package
```

I tried removing the current installation with `sudo apt purge r-base r-base-core r-recommended` and reinstalling it with `sudo apt install r-base r-base-core r-recommended` but it doesn't seem to help.

When I removed my old version of R is manually removed `.libPaths` folders. I have later tried to recreate them (without the installed packages) but this didn't solve the problem.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Running `R --vanilla` returns the same Fatal error

Comment: It's possible. The first entry `libgcr-base-3-1:amd64` shows `3.36.0-2build1`, but the rest is `4.0.3-1.2004.0`. Could this be the reason? If so, how to solve it?

Comment: Still nothing ;/

Answer (score 1):

Hi Do you still have the same problem?
I solved it moving the library folder in my Documents folder, then I have created a new library flder in usr/lib/R and I have then moved again all the folders inside from Documents.
The issue is that something has changed in the permission rights and R is not able to open the folder. Actually if you run "sudo R" in your terminal this should work but sudo R in not the right way to use R

Comment: In the process of solving the original issue I messed up my Ubuntu so I reinstalled it. I could use the latest R by doing a fresh installation.